# OS won’t boot during Visual Studio 2010 install on vista 64

Tags: windows-vista, reboot, visual-studio-2010, safe-mode

I am installing Visual Studio 2010 on a vista 64 bits machine.

During the install it asked for a restart.

Since that, vista won't load. I tried restore to previous good configuration - didn't help.

I am only able to boot it using safe mode with networking. When I did that, it continued the vista part of the install (the screen with the 3 out of 3 updates) but after that when I restarted again - still fails.

Answer (score 0):

at the end of the day, it was an unrelated issue, that the computer user failed to report about